# Woocommerce - Cart page not displaying

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shopping-cart, missing-data

After ADD TO CART option i can see the items are getting updated to **CART** but when moving to **cart page** it is redirecting back to **homepage**.

[image]

The cart page shortcode is also provided.

[image]

Please help out!I'm new to woocommerce.

Answer (score 18):

Be sure you have page.php setup in your theme to get the content. Something like:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

  <?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 9):

So I fixed mine, here is how I did it, seems woocommerce does not create all the pages in the newest version, you are missing the 'cart page'.. create a page name it 'cart' then place this short code on the page.. [woocommerce_cart] save..Tada.. ;o)

Shop – No content required.
Cart – Contains [woocommerce_cart] shortcode and shows the cart contents
Checkout – Contains [woocommerce_checkout] shortcode and shows information such as shipping and payment options
My Account – Contains [woocommerce_my_account] shortcode and shows each customer information related to their account, orders, etc.

Answer (score 5):

In wordpress 5.4.x it is here like in this image:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Dear go to woo commerce setting page and click to checkout tab then select the cart page for add to cart.

[image]

you should also need to reset your permalinks first default and then post name.

Comment: I have already configured all these things  . Still its not working .

Comment: provide website link

Comment: its in localhost

Comment: the reset your woocommerce

Answer (score 2):

This question is from years ago but since I had the same problem and finally could find the culprit by try and error, I post this answer in case someone has the same struggle. Go to woocomerce setting and then advance and set the checkout and cart pages
If the woocommerce doesn't create checkout and cart pages when you install it, you need to create them by yourself using these pieces of codes:

[woocommerce_cart]
[woocommerce_checkout]

You can find other codes from here:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/pages-not-displaying/#

Answer (score 0):

Adding these shortcodes worked for me: [woocommerce_cart] [woocommerce_checkout].
Seems the pages were not created during woocommerce installation.
Create cart page: add the short code:[woocommerce_cart]
Create checkout page and add the short corde: [woocommerce_checkout]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).